# If $\sum a_n$ converges does it imply $\sum a_n^3$ converges?

Tags: calculus

As title says does the converges of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i$ imply that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (a_i)^3$ converge?

Comment: Please clarify: Is $a_n$ real valued? I suspect one can construct a complex-valued $a_n$ that would serve as a counter-example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we assume $a_i\leq 0$ or $a_i\geq 0$ from some point on the statement is obviously true.
If we remove the crucial assumption about the sign, it might not. Let
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{\log^2(n+2)}\cdot\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}1&\text{if}&n\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\1&\text{if}&n\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\-2&\text{if}&n\equiv 0\pmod{3}\end{array}\right.$$
It it simple to check that $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ is convergent, but $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n^3$ is not, essentially by Kronecker's lemma (summation by parts).

Comment: Nice. I tried $a_n = \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ with the same $+1,+1,-2$ and this should also work.

Comment: @Winther: agreed. It is enough to have $b_n>0$ such that $\sum b_n^3$ is divergent but $\sum b_n/n$ is convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never even heard of this lemma nor did i think about this kind of counter-point.

Answer (score 4):

Let's define the sequence by $a_{3k-2}=2/\sqrt[3]{k}$, $a_{3k-1}=a_{3k}=-1/\sqrt[3]{k}$, note that the sum of these three consecutive terms is $0$. But $a_{3k-2}^3+a_{3k-1}^3+a_{3k}^3=6/k$

From here, it's easy to check that $\sum a_n=0$ but $\sum a_n^3$ diverges.

Comment: You may want to start with $n=4$ because if $n=1,2,3$ then $k=0$. Otherwise, change the indexing of $a_n$.

Answer (score -1):

$\textbf{Hint: }$ If 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$
converge, then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Which means, there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n|<1$ for all $n\ge N$. Then $|a_n|^3=|a_n^3|<|a_n|$, and hence
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n^3$$
converge (the absolute convergence is necessary).

Comment: Yes, but without the absulute convergence is that statment true?

Comment: @Dustbony: without absolute convergence, no.