# True or false: if $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {a_n} $ converges then so does $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {{{\left( {a_n} \right)}^3}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**True or false:**

If $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{a_n}} $ is a convergent series of real numbers then $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( {{a_n}} \right)}^3}} $ is also convergent.

**My attempt:**

Note that since the series converges, we have $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = 0$ and thus ${a_n} \le 1$ for a large enough $n$.

The claim is obviously true if ${a_n} \ge 0$ since if that's the case then ${\left( {{a_n}} \right)^3} \le {a_n}$ for a large enough $n$ and by a comparison theorem (for non negative series) we conclude that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( {{a_n}} \right)}^3}} $ converges.

The claim is also true if ${a_n} < 0$ for all natural $n$ by symmetry. 
Since ${a_n} < 0$ iff ${\left( {{a_n}} \right)^3} < 0$.

But I'm stuck if ${a_n}$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative.
I've tried to take a "classic" example like $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}} \over n}} $$
But that doesn't disprove the claim.

Hints would be welcome!

Comment: Hint. Try the ratio test. The absolute value there is your friend.

Comment: See also: [If $\sum a_n$ converges does it imply $\sum a_n^3$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3267930/9464)